# Passing Enum to ASCX via html markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I've this ASCX:

```
public partial class TopPhoto : UserControl
{

    public TopPhotoEnum Mode { get; set; }
    public int PhotoNumber { get; set; }
...
```

I want to set those property via html markup like this:

```
 <uc1:TopPhoto ID="TopPhoto1" runat="server" Mode="TopPhotoEnum.Today" PhotoNumber="5" />
```

**update**

```
public enum TopPhotoEnum
{
    Today,Week,Month,Year,AllTime
}
```

but this returns me an error like this:

```
 Impossible to create object of type 'UpVoteEntities.TopPhotoEnum' from string 'TopPhotoEnum.AllTime' property 'Mode'.
```

Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
<uc1:TopPhoto ID="TopPhoto1" runat="server" Mode="Today" PhotoNumber="5" />
```

But it depends on how and where your enum is defined.

Comment: Did you try this suggestion? If the enum ( spelt correctly! ) is publically available you shoudl be able to use it without the qualification.